# Keep the business working hours which pass midnight

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

For example: I run a cash register from `21:00 to 08:30` on `Wednesday` meaning It opens on `Wednesday 21:00` and closes on `Thursday 08:30` I am storing the working hours of the register as minutes from `0 - 1440`:

```
"cashRegister" : {
        "Monday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        },
        "Tuesday" : {
            "open" : 1140,
            "close" : 420
        },
        "Wednesday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        },
        "Thursday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        },
        "Friday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        },
        "Saturday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        },
        "Sunday" : {
            "open" : 1260,
            "close" : 510
        }
    }
```

now for instance I logged in to my system at: `Thursday 01:00` and  my cash register started working on `Wednesday 21:00` I would like to return the following period: `from: 2017-01-11T21:00:00 to: 2017-01-12T08:30:00` 
the problem is if I login at: `2017-01-11T22:00:00` for example. I can check whether on `2017-01-11 (Wednesday)` the register is working pass midnight `open > close` and add 1 day to get: `2017-01-12T08:30:00` however if I login at `2017-01-12T01:30:00` I'm on `Thursday` If i do the same I end up with: `2017-01-12T21:00:00 - 2017-01-13T08:30:00` which is wrong because the register works from: `2017-01-11T21:00:00 to: 2017-01-12T08:30:00` and not: `2017-01-12T21:00:00 to: 2017-01-13T08:30:00` so baically I just need to understand if the register works pass midnight, and we are actually pass midnight NOW.. I tried to do:

```js
const cashRegister = {
            "Monday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            },
            "Tuesday" : {
                "open" : 1140,
                "close" : 420
            },
            "Wednesday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            },
            "Thursday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            },
            "Friday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            },
            "Saturday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            },
            "Sunday" : {
                "open" : 1260,
                "close" : 510
            }
        };

const todayUTC      = moment.utc().startOf('day');
const day           = todayUTC.format('dddd');
const registerToday = cashRegister[day];
const openingAt     = moment.utc(registerToday.open * 60000);
const closingAt     = moment.utc(registerToday.close * 60000);
const result = {};

  result.openingAt = todayUTC.clone().set({
     hour: openingAt.hours(),
     minute: openingAt.minutes(),
     second: 0,
  })
  result.closingAt = todayUTC.clone().set({
     hour: closingAt.hours(),
     minute: closingAt.minutes(),
     second: 0,
  }).add(openingAt > closingAt ? 1 : 0, 'days')

console.log(result) // perfect results

// if we check 1 minute after 00:00. we return bad results...

const minuteAfterTodayUTC  = moment.utc().endOf('day').add(1, 'minute');
const day2                 = minuteAfterTodayUTC.format('dddd');
const registerToday2       = cashRegister[day2];
const openingAt2           = moment.utc(registerToday2.open * 60000);
const closingAt2           = moment.utc(registerToday2.close * 60000);
const result2              = {};

  result2.openingAt2 = minuteAfterTodayUTC.clone().set({
     hour: openingAt2.hours(),
     minute: openingAt2.minutes(),
     second: 0,
  })
  result2.closingAt2 = minuteAfterTodayUTC.clone().set({
     hour: closingAt2.hours(),
     minute: closingAt2.minutes(),
     second: 0,
  }).add(openingAt > closingAt ? 1 : 0, 'days')

console.log(result2) // bad results
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should try to refine your question, it's not very clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess "cashRegister" is the times that the register is working, and wherever *open* is greater than *close* then it's going over midnight.

If you access the register at any particular time I guess you want either the current working period, or the one that most recently finished. Storing the open and close times as minutes just makes it harder to work out when they are for humans reading the values, but I guess simplifies coding.

Your code seems overly complex, so I'll just post an alternative. For any date, the following returns either the session it's in or the one most recently finished. So if it's just before the start of a session, it will return the previous one.

```js
var sessions = {Monday    :{open: 1260, close: 510},
                Tuesday   :{open: 1140, close: 420},
                Wednesday :{open: 1260, close: 510},
                Thursday  :{open: 1260, close: 510},
                Friday    :{open: 1260, close: 510},
                Saturday  :{open: 1260, close: 510},
                Sunday    :{open: 1260, close: 510}};

function getDayName(date) {
  return 'Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday'.split(' ')[date.getDay()];
}

function getSessionByDate(sessions, date) {
  
  // Get the day name
  var day = getDayName(date);
  
  // Create dates for start and end, adjust later
  var start = new Date(+date);
  var end; // set later when start worked out
  
  // Get the session for the current day
  var session = sessions[day];
  
  // If session start is after current time in minutes, then
  // session started yesterday so set start and session to yesterday
  var currentTimeInMinutes = date.getHours()*60 + date.getMinutes();

  if (currentTimeInMinutes < session['open']) {
    start.setDate(start.getDate() - 1);
    day = getDayName(start);
    session = sessions[day];
  }
  // Set start to session start
  start.setHours(0,session['open'],0,0);
  // For end, use start date and set hours to 24 and minutes to close
  end = new Date(+start);
  end.setHours(24, session['close'],0,0);

  return [start,end];
}

[new Date(2017,0,10, 2,12,53), // Wednesday 10 January at 02:12:53 (during session)
 new Date(2017,0,10, 9,12,53), // Wednesday 10 January at 09:12:53 (after session end)
 new Date(2017,0,10,23,12,53), // Wednesday 10 January at 23:12:53 (during session)
 new Date(2017,0,21,13,34,18)  // Saturday 21 January at 13:34:18 (after session end)

].forEach(function(d) {
  var session = getSessionByDate(sessions, d)
  var opts = {weekday:'short', day:'2-digit',month:'short',year:'numeric',hour:'numeric',minute:'numeric'};
  console.log('On ' + d.toLocaleString('en-GB', opts) + '\n' +
              'Session start: ' + session[0].toLocaleString('en-GB', opts) +
              '\nSession end  : ' + session[1].toLocaleString('en-GB', opts)
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot that looks good! Is there any way to repeat it using moment()?

Comment: The only things moment.js can help with are getting the day name (which is trivial) and formatting the output (not difficult either). I can't see that it helps otherwise. Any other formatting library will do the same, e.g. [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) is much smaller and does everything required. But I'm no moment.js guru. ;-)